# Get threads + username of last poster

Tags: php, mysql, forum

So, I'm writing a small forum and i want to list the following

- the threads topic
- the username of the who started the thread
- the date when it was started
- the username of the last person who wrote in the thread
- date of the last post

I have three tables for this

account

```
+---------------+
| id | username |
|---------------+
| 1  | blargh   |
| 2  | hest     |
+---------------+
```

threads

```
+----+-------+------+---------+
| id | topic | user | thedate |
+----+-------+------+---------+
| 5  | Yarr  | 1    | bleh    |
+-------------------+---------+
```

posts

```
+----+---------+------+---------+--------+
| id | content | user | thedate | thread |
+----+---------+------+---------+--------+
| 8  | aaaa    | 1    | aadate  | 5      |
+----+---------+------+---------+--------+
| 9  | bbbb    | 2    | bbdate  | 5      |
+----+---------+------+---------+--------+
```

What i want:

```
+----+-------+----------+---------+--------------------+----------------+
| id | topic | username | thedate | last_post_username | last_post_date |
+----+-------+----------+---------+--------------------+----------------+
| 5  | Yarr  | blarg    | bleh    | hest               | bbdate         |
+----+-------+----------+---------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT
forum_threads.id AS id,
forum_threads.topic AS topic,
forum_threads.time AS time,
accounts.username AS username,
Max(forum_posts.id) AS latest_post_id,
forum_posts.`user` AS `user`,
forum_posts.timeposted AS last_post_time
FROM
((forum_threads
JOIN forum_posts ON ((forum_posts.thread = forum_threads.id)))
JOIN accounts ON ((forum_threads.`user` = accounts.id)))
```

I can't seem to get the username for the last poster and time for said post

Comment: Why not just use the mature forum software that's already been over the web for years and years?

Comment: Your tables and "what you want" don't match up very well with your query, which makes it more difficult to write a good answer for you, but probably the easiest way to get what you want is to add a where condition that requires the `forum_posts.timeposted` be equal to a subquery that returns the max `timeposted` from forum_posts where `thread = forum_threads.id`.

Comment: Everything above the query describes my problem. The query is more of an "I got this far"-thing.

Answer (score 0):

First -- I don't see anything in your schema that links posts to threads. My answer is assuming that there's an additional column in `posts` called `threadid`.

The most common solution I've seen to this problem is to track the ID (and possibly user ID and username) of the most recent post in the `threads` table. It's easy to get the most recent post if all you need is the ID:

```
SELECT threadid, MAX(id) FROM posts WHERE <...> GROUP BY threadid
```

But there's no efficient way to get the associated time or user ID from that query. The closest I can get is this mess:

```
SELECT threadid, id, user, username, thedate FROM posts
WHERE posts.id IN (
    SELECT threadid, MAX(id) FROM posts WHERE <...> GROUP BY threadid
)
```

Which is incredibly inefficient on MySQL -- the optimizer completely falls apart on subqueries with a `GROUP BY`. (The query takes about 300 ms on a test database with under a hundred threads.) Just bite your tongue, denormalize the database by storing information on the most recent post in the thread, and everything will be OK.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct, there should be a threadid column in the post table.